# HXTT excel driver connection issue

Tags: java, excel, tomcat7, hxtt

I am using HXTT excel driver to get data from an excel file. 
The data directory is not in the Windows machine where the Java program should run, but instead those Excel files are in IMB machine.

Let's say my excel file on IBM is in //MyApp/folder/data.xlsx. I am trying to connect following way:

```
BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
dataSource.setDriverClassName(com.hxtt.sql.excel.ExcelDriver);
dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:excel://///MyApp/folder/data.xlsx?maxScanRows=31");
Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection()
```

But I am getting the following exception:

```
org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (//MyApp/folder/data.xlsx doesn't exist or can't be accessed. If you're using mapped drives to access database files, you may need to check the security permissions.)
```

Is there any difference in URLs when connecting to IBM machine?